# Windows installer: Selected boot device failed!

Tags: debian, windows, dual-boot

I'm trying to install Windows 10 or 7, burnt on USB drive, along-side Debian 11; but i receive the following error while booting windows' installer:

> Selected boot device failed. Press any key to reboot the system.

I've tried both *UEFI* and *Legacy* modes, and also *enabled* or *disabled* *secure boot*, but non worked.
There are two partitions, one have Debian installed and one empty for Windows. how can i skip this error?

There are similar issues on the internet but none worked for me!

GParted screenshot:
[image]

System: Dell Latitude 7480

Comment: Please edit your question and add a screenshot of `gparted`.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Screenshot added.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

- Your 1st partition is marked as bootable and it's not NTFS/FAT32 - Windows cannot work in this configuration. Also, once you install Windows you'll lose access to your Linux unless you reinstall the GRUB bootloader.
- Windows may decline to be installed on a logical partition.  This can be fixed by deleting `sda2`.

Here's how I'd go about the situation:

1. Remove the boot flag on sda1
2. Delete sda2
3. Install Windows
4. Boot from a USB Linux stick and reinstall GRUB
5. Boot into Linux and rebuild `grub.cfg`, so that you could boot into Windows.